# Errors converting VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

Im trying convert at vb.net console file into C#, but i got 3 errors when i tried to run the console application, here are the errors.

```
Error   2   Single-line comment or end-of-line expected


private static MySettings defaultInstance = (MySettings)global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new MySettings());
    #region "My.Settings Auto-Save Functionality"
    #if _MyType = "WindowsForms"    

Error   3   Single-line comment or end-of-line expected

        get {
            #if _MyType = "WindowsForms"
            if (!addedHandler) {
                lock (addedHandlerLockObject) {
                    if (!addedHandler) {
                        My.Application.Shutdown += AutoSaveSettings;
                        addedHandler = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            #endif
            return defaultInstance;


thanx
```

Comment: `My` is generally something used in VB.NET.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think `this` is the C# equivalent.  So `My.Application.Shutdown` would be `this.Application.Shutdown`.

Comment: @Tim `My` is something that does not exist in C#. For `My.Application` OP should seek an answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6ae4c08-98f5-4ae5-bf74-cffdb427be1e/c-equivalent-of-myapplication?forum=vsx).

Comment: @Tim VB equivalent for `this` is not `My` but `Me`. `My` is a sort of object that contains a lot of unrelated stuff.

Comment: AgentFire and Lucas - thanks.  I don't do a lot of VB.NET and got `Me` and `My` mixed up.

Comment: you can use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ or http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html

Answer (score 2):

That's a build error, not a run-time error.  In c#, the #if directive is much more limited than in other languages.  From the [language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

> When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined. Unlike C and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol; the #if statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

And note also the limitations of #define.  Again from the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx):

> You use #define to define a symbol. When you use the symbol as the expression that's passed to the #if directive, the expression will evaluate to true, as the following example shows:
>
> #define DEBUG
>
> The #define directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as static members of a class or struct. If you have several such constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold them.

So you need to do something like

```
#define WindowsForms
#if (!WindowsForms)
#define WPF
#endif
```

at the beginning of your file(s) rather than having a single preprocessor symbol with many possible values.  For project-wide preprocessor symbols, use a [/define option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) when compiling the project.

More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).